# Magento getStoreConfig quest. on elance.com

Tags: magento

On elance.com there is a question about getStoreConfig function. Most probably such question exist on certification exam.

```
Which one of the following xpaths can be read using Mage::getStoreConfig('some/value')?

Answers:

• default/some/value
• some/value
• some/value/default
• global/default/some/value
• stores/some/value
```

This service tells that correct answer is 'stores/some/value'. But if we look into the code we will see:

```
public static function getStoreConfig($path, $store = null)
{
    return self::app()->getStore($store)->getConfig($path);
}

public function getConfig($path)
{
    if (isset($this->_configCache[$path])) {
        return $this->_configCache[$path];
    }

    $config = Mage::getConfig();

    $fullPath = 'stores/' . $this->getCode() . '/' . $path;
    $data = $config->getNode($fullPath);
    if (!$data && !Mage::isInstalled()) {
        $data = $config->getNode('default/' . $path);
    }
    if (!$data) {
        return null;
    }
    return $this->_processConfigValue($fullPath, $path, $data);
}
```

It means that correct answer is:

```
$fullPath = 'stores/' . $this->getCode() . '/' . $path;
(stores/default{or some another store}/some/value)
```

or

```
$data = $config->getNode('default/' . $path);
(default/some/value)
```

If we debug this, we can see, that stores has only admin and storenames child nodes. Could anybody please clarify this? Did I miss anything?

Answer (score 2):

You are right and the Elance exam is wrong.

Possible Xpaths are:

- `default/some/value` (default configuration)
- `stores/[store]/some/value` (store configuration)